# Why do the Black Star Dragon Balls exist?

Tags: dragon-ball-gt

1. If Kami made the Black Star Dragon Balls, why didn't Dende have to recreate them like he did with the original ones?
2. Why did Kami make the Black Star Dragon Balls in the first place? Namekians are supposed to be peaceful.
3. Why weren't the Black Star Dragon Balls scattered? They were all together when Pilaf found them. (How did Pilaf get past Korin)

Answer (score 7):

1. Kami didn't create the Black Star Dragon Balls. The entity known as the Nameless Namekian did. This is from the [Dragon Ball Wiki](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Star_Dragon_Ball):

   > The Black Star Dragon Balls, or Ultimate Dragon Balls, are a more powerful version of the main Dragon Balls, created by the Nameless Namekian (before Kami and King Piccolo split).

   So Dende not having to recreate them is possibly due to there being a different set of rules applied to them. Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to point out when the Nameless Namekian made these Black Star Balls. However, it would make sense that the regular Dragon Balls had more restricting rules, since Kami had a responsibility as Earth's guardian to make sure they wouldn't fall into the wrong hands, so it would make sense for them to be rendered useless by his death.
2. Since now we know it wasn't Kami but the Nameless Namekian who made them, except that we don't know the exact time he made them, it could be inferred they were made during a time when the Nameless Namekian began developing a bit of a corrupted side within him with less than perfect intentions. The side that would later becomes King Piccolo.
3. They weren't scattered because they were supposed to be hidden. Since Kami had knowledge of the Nameless Namekian in him, he and possibly Mr. Popo thought it would be better to keep watch over them. Again, from the Dragon Ball Wiki:

   > The only people who would have known of the existence of the balls would have been Piccolo (due to him having all of Kami's knowledge) and possibly Mr. Popo, but King Kai also knew of their existence.

   Although it probably wasn't smart to keep them all in one place, GT never really did make much sense.

   Also, this slipped by me the first time around, but to further prove GT's logic isn't really logic, look at this snippet about the [Black Star balls](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Star_Dragon_Ball):

   > After the wish has been granted, the [Black Star] Dragon Balls spread across the universe... If all seven balls have not been re-collected and returned to the planet on which the wish was granted in one year, the planet will explode. In the Japanese version, Mr. Popo insists that not only must they be returned to the planet they were used on, but they must be returned to their original spot, hence why Earth still exploded a year

   So not only did the Nameless Namekian make them, but once a wish was granted, he could never get to them again. Is space flight common already at that point in time? If it was, why make it near impossible to track the balls again without a Dragon Radar within a year, thus killing the Earth's populace?

   Last but not least, if Kami did have knowledge (which would've later transferred over to Piccolo by them fusing and becoming the Nameless Namekian again), why not go ahead and destroy the Dark Star Dragon Balls before all the drama?

Answer (score 1):

1. Dende didn't have to recreate them because when created Piccolo and Kami were joined together, then they split which then would make them disappear until when they joined back together again during the cell saga henceforth bringing them back; but being forgotten about they were never used.
2. The Black Star Dragon Balls would have been the first ones made on earth, and being made by the nameless Namekian whom would have been evil at the time would have something to do with it, but it's possible that they were made so powerful accidentally that they basically sacrifice the planet they're used on for whatever is desired. Of course unless they're collected and returned.
3. The Black Star Dragon Balls had to be together because they probably seemed safest at the lookout and they all have to be on the same planet otherwise the last one that they were used on would blow up in a year. Plus it would make sense having to be kept at the lookout because the guardians are supposed to protect them since they endanger the earth if used, but Dende's a noob so you gotta cut him some slack.